# Convert decimal int into binary

Tags: java

The task i have is to write a method which converts any decimal number to binary, the number is given as an int and the converted (binary) number should also be returned as an int.
Now i got somewhat of a solution, but i dont know how to save the converted number as an int, as I'm working with a string in my method! I feel like `.parseInt()` would be too easy, because then I could also just use `. toBinaryString()`

```
static void intToBin (int a) {

String bin = "";

while (a > 0) {
    if ( a % 2 == 0 )
        bin = bin + "0";
    else
        bin = bin + "1";
    a /= 2;
}

for (int i = 0; i < bin.length();i ++) {
    System.out.print(bin.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the value to be when you convert say, the decimal number 43 to an int and print it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; it's already an int. "Converting" it to binary then converting it back to an `int` again seems... odd.

Answer (score 1):

First, binary representation is just that,  the value of a decimal number into a binary string.  Or decimal is just a representation of a binary number.  If you convert  a binary number to an int it will be a decimal number (whether it has only 1's and 0's or not).

```
int a = 1001;  //is a decimal number  == 1,001
int b = 0b1001; //is a decimal number == 9
```

The above would print in decimal because that is the default output representation of the print methods.  Internally, all numbers are 1's and 0's (or possibly even +5v and 0v depending on how specific you want to be).

If you want to convert a binary string to decimal, do it similarly.  Except instead of dividing by the two and getting the remainder, you multiply by two.

```
int sum =0
String s = "11011";  //27
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
   sum = sum * 2 + (c-'0'); // multiply by 2 and add the bit.
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
27
```

Note that I don't need to store it as a string since decimal is the default representation (as I explained earlier).

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you're asking for:

```java
public static int decimalToBinary(int a) {
    String result = "";
    while (a > 0) {
        int res = a % 2;
        a = a / 2;
        result = res + result;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = etxtDecimal.getText().toString();
binary = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(text));
```

It is. We use `toBinaryString` to convert decimal to binary

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, instead of needing the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bin.length();i ++) {
    System.out.print(bin.charAt(i));
}
```

the digits could be added *in front* to the result:

```
...
if ( a % 2 == 0 )
    bin = "0" + bin;
else
    bin = "1" + bin;
...
System.out.println(bin);
```

(could also just add the result of `a % 2`, without the need of the `if` <sub>not sure if better</sub>)

---

if you want to save the binary representation as an `int` (bit strange, confusing). 
Example: input `5`, output `101`

```
int bin = 0;
int mult = 1;
while (a > 0) {
    if (a % 2 == 1) {
        bin += mult;
    }
    mult *= 10;
    a /= 2;
}
```

<sup>not tested, just an idea, to inspire</sup>